# Good Flash PageFlip Template/Program

Tags: jquery, flash, templates

I'm wondering what the best flash pageflip template is?
I prefer a free version but am willing to check out paid ones as well for sure.

I'm looking for one that I can just load a PDF into and it will build it for me, ready to go with the template.
I'm also open to any alternatives (such as a jQuery one) if there are better methods.

This is a good example of one but I'm not sure how good it is and would like to be able to change the look of the buttons: http://www.flashpageflip.com/demos/free/

Thanks a lot, any suggestions or insight would be very much appreciated,
Wade

Comment: they have a pdf publisher - http://page-flip.com/

Comment: That looked really good. Unfortunately there's no version for mac it looks like.

Comment: @ Wade D Ouellet - it needs .NET 3.5, i know it was somehow launched on mac but maybe on the virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.pressmo.com You can use it for free or commercial version (without branding). 
Converted publication you can download and integrate with your own website (own hosting).

...and video tutorial...how to work
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwV4qXbqauk

Answer (score 0):

**Flex** based. Not so fast to implement, and no pdf  compatible but looks really nice in the end, and has some useful features. [link](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/flex-book-component-beta)